# [MYSQL]: Using SELECT statements to query occurrences of a unique key that exist in another column in the same Table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

What I am trying to find out is to find the employee id, salary of supervisors, and the total number of employees directly supervised by each one of them.

I have the following Employees Table:
[image]

I am new to mysql, and am currently stuck at this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alias for this job
try this query with your parameters

select employee_id, Salary, job_title, (select count(*) from table where supervisor_id = short_name1.employee_id) as total_team from table as short_name1 where job_title = "supervisor"

Comment: Ohhh, thank you so much ! It works exactly like how it should be.